# Can a single Google Sheets filter view show OR conditions in multiple columns simultaneously?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter-view

I am trying to make a spreadsheet for my teachers that will assign them particular students to call each day based on how many periods they are absent during the day. I currently have a hyperlink set up on the Dashboard page so teachers can click their names and see a filter view of which calls they need to make for 8/24. Is it possible to make a single filter view that would simultaneously show where their name is assigned for 8/24 in Column H AND where their name is assigned for 8/25 in Column O? My goal is for them to click a single hyperlink on the Dashboard which takes them to all the calls they need to make for the week WITHOUT me having to make five separate links for each day of the week.

[image: Current filter view]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Create a column that concatenates H & O, and put the filter on that column, e.g Contains

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You should extend the Filter View range to cover the other columns you need to filter.

In this case for the "Amber" Filter View, you should have Range: `A1:P116`. Then select the proper filter on the column H and O: `Filter by Values: Amber`.

With the filter view still open, copy the URL in your browser and paste it in the `HYPERLINK` formula you have in the "Dashboard" Sheet.